# "Error Domain Code=324" while upload photo using Facebook method

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am working with the Facebook method API with iPhone-SDK.  After authorizing, I tried to upload an image, using this code:

```
NSString *link = @"http://www.google.com/logos/2011/houdini11-hp.jpg";  
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:link];  
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];  
    UIImage *img1  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data1];  
    NSMutableDictionary *photos = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                                img1, @"picture",   
                                  nil];    
    [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"  
                  andParams:photos  
              andHttpMethod:@"POST"  
                andDelegate:self];
```

I got this error:

> error DOMAIN = Operation could not be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 324.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you tried to use NSString *link = @"http://www.google.com/logos/2011/houdini11-hp.jpg";  
NSMutableDictionary *photos = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                                @"image", @"type", link, @"src"   
                                  nil];    
    [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"  
                  andParams:photos  
              andHttpMethod:@"POST"  
                andDelegate:self];

Comment: No.  i think we can't give the link in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all error code here..

http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.html

So error is Missing or invalid image file